# Google Map API TypeError: this[Dc] is not a function

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm following the [Google Maps tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map) and I get this error

```
TypeError: this[Dc] is not a function
    at Object.yl [as Map] (main.js:57)
    at core.util.js:49
    at ionic.bundle.js:48811
    at Object.ionic.Platform.ready (ionic.bundle.js:2122)
    at Object.self.ready (ionic.bundle.js:48809)
    at Object.self.loadMap (core.util.js:47)
    at eventDetail.controller.js:598
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:23394)
    at ionic.bundle.js:23410
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:24673)
```

Here is my code sample

```
  // src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"
  loadMap: function(location, domId) {
    var lat, lon, mapCanvas, options;
    if (domId == null) {
      domId = 'map-canvas';
    }
    lat = location[0], lon = location[1];
    mapCanvas = document.getElementById(domId);
    options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeid: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    return $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      var map;
      return map = google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, options);
    });
```

I have stepped through the code and confirmed that the domElement is available. Any thoughts?

Comment: The [code in the tutorial works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/r9dyxyau/).  Perhaps something you changed broke it.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue.  What is $ionicPlatform?

Comment: $ionicPlatform.ready fires after the window load event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.  You are missing the `new` before `google.maps.Map`.

Actually you have two, javascript is case sensitive, but the second doesn't cause an issue:

```
mapTypeid: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
```

should be:

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
```

[Proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9dyxyau/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function loadMap(location, domId) {
  var lat, lon, mapCanvas, options;
  if (domId == null) {
    domId = 'map-canvas';
  }
  lat = location[0], lon = location[1];
  mapCanvas = document.getElementById(domId);
  options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, options);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  loadMap([42, -72], "map");

});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```